# Find the probablity given the condition?

Tags: probability

If ABCD be any random 4-digit number in `base 11`, what is the probability that A < B < C < D?

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends.  We allowing leading zeros?

Comment: No..It must be a 4 digit.No leading zeros.

Comment: This changes the problem then.

Answer (score 4):

The desired probability is just the number of four-digit numbers of the desired type divided by the total number of four-digit numbers.

In base eleven there are eleven possible digits. The first digit of a four-digit number can be any of the ten digits other than $0$, and each of the other three can be any of the $11$ digits, so there are $10\cdot11^3$ possible four-digit numbers.

If $ABCD$ is a four-digit number in which $A<B<C<D$, then $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is a four-element subset of the set of $10$ non-zero digits, since none of the digits can be $0$. Conversely, if I take any four distinct non-zero digits, they can be used to form exactly one four-digit number $ABCD$ in which $A<B<C<D$. How many four-element subsets are there of a set of ten things?

Comment: This is restating the question.

Comment: @Neil: No, it's providing a very large hint by doing most of the problem and leaving the last step or to for vikiiii to finish.

Comment: @Neil: No. $ $ $  $